# Suppose that $A$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix and $A^3=2A$. Prove that $\det(A)=0$ or $\det(A)=\pm 4$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Suppose that $A$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix and $A^3=2A$. Prove that $\det(A)=0$ or $\det(A)=\pm 4$.

---

I already proved that $\det(A)=\pm 4,$ but I'm having problems when proving that $\det(A)=0.$

Comment: How did you prove the determinant is $\pm 4$? Also, it's relevant to know the size of $A$, what is it?

Comment: You cannot have possibly proved what you claim, since it is false.

Comment: Are you sure of the question ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say the matrix is 4x4.

Comment: So, we know that $det(A^3)=det(A^2)*det(A)$ and $det(2A)=2^4*det(A)$,
$det(A^2)*det(A) = 2^4*det(A)$,
$\frac{det(A^2)*det(A)}{det(A)}=16$,
$det(A^2)=16$
And then you just apply de square root in both sides and you get that $det(A)=+-4$

Comment: To form that fraction, you implicitly assumed $\det A \neq 0$, which is precisely the other case to consider (it requires no more than a moment's thought).

Comment: And how do you know you can divide by $\det(A)$?

Comment: As a point of order, if you could actually prove that $\pm 4$ were the only possibilities, then you have still successfully proven that the determinant is either $\pm4$ or $0$. There is, a priori, no need to show that $0$ is possible in order to satisfy the problem.

Comment: You have already proved it. you already got that $\det(A)^3-16\det(A)=0$ which means $\det(A)$ is a root of the equation $x^3-16x=0$, which has precisely $3$ roots, namely $0,\pm4$.

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there.

$A^3=2A\to (\det A)^3=2^4\det A$

$(\det A)^3-16\det A=0$

$\det A\left((\det A)^2-16\right)=0$

and finally $\det A = 0 $ or $\det A=\pm 4$.